# plpgSQL function query with cursor

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

As a true student, I'm working on my course work in the last night:)
But I tried to write this query for a few days and I don't know what to do. So that's why I'm writing here.

Sorry for this maybe stupid question, but all of us did first steps in programming some time ago with lots of mistakes and questions. (And sorry for my English, it's now perfect).

By the way, my task:

We have 3 tables (regions, cities and experiments [named 'data']). Third table (experiments ['data']) has so2_d field (content of so2 in air on specific date).

I need to create a report about maximum so2 content distribution in each city's air, using quarters of certain year(it doesn't matter which exactly).
Namely, the table have to look like this:

[image: table]

That means we need to sum so2 by horisontal and also vertical ways.

I tried to do it with 1 cursor, 2 cursors... It didn't work. In most cases I had this error: so2 is ambiguous.

Here is my code example. (I know it's bad and not ended, but I hope you will understand sth):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION so2_report()
    RETURNS text AS
    $$
    DECLARE
    name_r regions.name_r %TYPE; name_c cities.name_c %TYPE; 
    quarter_1 data.so2_d %TYPE := 0; quarter_2 data.so2_d %TYPE := 0; quarter_3 data.so2_d %TYPE := 0; quarter_4 data.so2_d %TYPE := 0;
    quarter INTEGER; counter INTEGER := 0;
    string TEXT;

    cursor1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT regions.name_r, cities.name_c FROM regions INNER JOIN cities USING (id_r) INNER JOIN data USING (id_c);

    cursor2 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT max(data.so2_d) FROM data WHERE EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = quarter AND data.id_c = counter;

    BEGIN

    string := repeat(' ', 90) || 'Report' || E'\n';
    string := string || repeat(' ', 65) || 'about maximum so2 content in air' || E'\n\n';

    string := string || repeat(' ', 5) || 'Region' || repeat(' ', 15) || 'City' || repeat(' ', 25) || 'I quarter' || repeat(' ', 10) ||
    'ІІ quarter' || repeat(' ', 10) || 'ІІІ quarter' || repeat(' ', 10) || 'IV quarter' || repeat(' ', 10) || 'All Year' || E'\n\n';

    OPEN cursor1;
    LOOP

    FETCH next FROM cursor1 INTO name_r, name_c;
    exit when not found;
    string := string || rpad(name_r, 25) || rpad(name_c, 25);

    OPEN cursor2;
    counter := counter + 1; 
    quarter := 0;
    LOOP
    quarter := quarter + 1;

    FETCH next FROM cursor2 INTO quarter_1, quarter_2, quarter_3, quarter_4;
    exit when not found;
    string := string || rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_1, '999.99'), 20) || 
    rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_2, '999.99'), 20) || rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_3, '999.99'), 20) || rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_4, '999.99'), 20) || E'\n';

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor2;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor1;


    RETURN string;
    END
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
    SELECT so2_report();



I will be grateful for any help.
```

***GUYS, I HAVE SOLVED IT! Here u got the code:***

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION s_report()
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE
name_r regions.name_r %TYPE; name_c cities.name_c %TYPE;
quarter_1 data.so2_d %TYPE; quarter_2 data.so2_d %TYPE; quarter_3 data.so2_d %TYPE; quarter_4 data.so2_d %TYPE;
year REAL; sum REAL ARRAY[5];
string TEXT;

cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT regions.name_r, cities.name_c,
                max( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 1 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_d) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) THEN so2_d ELSE 0 END ) As Quarter_1,
        max( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 2 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_d) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) THEN so2_d ELSE 0 END ) As Quarter_2,
        max( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 3 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_d) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) THEN so2_d ELSE 0 END ) As Quarter_3,
        max( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 4 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_d) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) THEN so2_d ELSE 0 END ) As Quarter_4
        FROM regions INNER JOIN cities USING (id_r) INNER JOIN data USING (id_c) GROUP BY regions.name_r, cities.name_c;


BEGIN
-- формуємо назву звіту
string := repeat(' ', 50) || 'Звіт' || E'\n';
string := string || repeat(' ', 27) || 'про розподіл максимальних значень SO2 в повітрі' || E'\n\n';
-- формуємо рядок заголовку звіту
string := string || repeat(' ', 5) || 'Область' || repeat(' ', 15) || 'Місто' || repeat(' ', 10) || 'I квартал' || repeat(' ', 5) ||
'ІІ квартал' || repeat(' ', 5) || 'ІІІ квартал' || repeat(' ', 5) || 'IV квартал' || repeat(' ', 5) || 'Рік' || E'\n\n';
--вперед
sum[1] := 0; sum[2] := 0; sum[3] := 0; sum[4] := 0; sum[5] := 0;
--відкриваємо курсор
OPEN cursor1;
LOOP
 --витягаємо значення з курсору
FETCH next FROM cursor1 INTO name_r, name_c, quarter_1, quarter_2, quarter_3, quarter_4;
exit when not found;
year := 0;
year := quarter_1 + quarter_2 + quarter_3 + quarter_4;
sum[1] := sum[1] + quarter_1;
sum[2] := sum[2] + quarter_2;
sum[3] := sum[3] + quarter_3;
sum[4] := sum[4] + quarter_4;
sum[5] := sum[5] + year;


string := string || rpad(name_r, 25) || rpad(name_c, 16) || rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_1, '999.99'), 16) || rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_2, '999.99'), 14) ||
rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_3, '999.99'), 15) || rpad(TO_CHAR(quarter_4, '999.99'), 12) || TO_CHAR(year, '999.99') || E'\n';

END LOOP;
CLOSE cursor1;
string := string || E'\n' || repeat(' ', 11) || rpad('Всього', 30) ||  rpad(TO_CHAR(sum[1], '999.99'), 16) || rpad(TO_CHAR(sum[2], '999.99'), 14) ||
rpad(TO_CHAR(sum[3], '999.99'), 15) || rpad(TO_CHAR(sum[4], '999.99'), 12) || TO_CHAR(sum[5], '999.99');

RETURN string;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
SELECT s_report();
```

Comment: You'll have a better chance to get a good answer if you show your tables (`\d table_name` in psql or copy ddl from pgAdmin).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet, so I can't post more than 2 links :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid procedural code as much as possible.
You are using SQL - one of the most beautiful **declarative** language.

---

If I properly guess your requirements and table's structures from your code, the below simple SQL statement should give you a result that is very close to your requirements:

```
SELECT regions.name_r, cities.name_c, 
       avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 1 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_1,
       avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 2 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_2,
       avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 3 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_3,
       avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 4 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_4
FROM regions 
INNER JOIN cities USING (id_r)
INNER JOIN data USING (id_c) 
GROUP BY regions.name_r, cities.name_c
;
```

Missing parts are a final sum of each quarter, and a sum for each year, and final totals.

This should be easy achieved with this query (not tested):

```
WITH dd As(
    SELECT regions.name_r, cities.name_c, 
           avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 1 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_1,
           avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 2 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_2,
           avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 3 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_3,
           avg( CASE WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM date_d) = 4 THEN so2_d END ) As Quarter_4
    FROM regions 
    INNER JOIN cities USING (id_r)
    INNER JOIN data USING (id_c) 
    GROUP BY regions.name_r, cities.name_c
)
SELECT dd.*,
       Quarter_1 + Quarter_2 + Quarter_3 + Quarter_4 As All_year
FROM dd
UNION All
SELECT 'TOTAL', NULL,
       SUM( Quarter_1 ),
       SUM( Quarter_2 ),
       SUM( Quarter_3 ),
       SUM( Quarter_4 ),
       SUM( Quarter_1 + Quarter_2 + Quarter_3 + Quarter_4 )
FROM dd
;
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but I need to do it using the function with cursor. I don't have free way to solve it :)